# Can we cite two pre-prints on Arxiv in one another?

Tags: arxiv, citations

I have two pre-prints posted on Arxiv. 2nd uses some definitions from first so I cited it. But if a reviewer raises some questions in first which have answer in second, can I cross cite them? Is it ethical and accepted? Or there are other ways to prevent question from being raised at the first place without citation?

Note: I cannot combine them because they have different themes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question, which I don’t think is right for MO. But… why would you think it would be unethical for two papers to cite one another? Why do you think questions would be raised?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for academia.stackexchange. That said, I see no problem in preprints citing each other, especially if they are released around the same time. But please note this might depend on the exact area and expectations in your field. I know a senior professor (in mathematics) who is submitting a series of 5 related preprints on the arXiv for publication _one at a time_; he is only submitting the next one to a journal once the previous one has been refereed. Hence why academia.SE might be a good idea to get a range of views.

Comment: Yes, and there is even a technical term to denote this. It's called hypertext: "Hypertext is a non-linear form of writing that allows readers to navigate through a text in a non-sequential way." So if your preprints reference each other, then this means you have created a hypertext, and there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: I have the impression the OP is mostly worried about creating a possible impression of circularity, rather than ethics.